# How to get keyword from peragraph from attachment description wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I have many attachments, In description of every image i have keyword in paragraph. Like this : `This is my first photo of my -Keyword-` 
My keyword always in `"-" like -Keyword-` so i want to get this keyword and want to print it on my theme template ( i mean single post.php file) so is their any way to achieve this. 
Thanks. (Sorry for my Bad English)

Update: 
Here is code

```
    <?php    
           /*VARS*/

  $posid    = $post->ID;

  $poslug   = $post->post_name;

  $permalink = $surl.'/'.$poslug.'/';


  $args = array(

        'numberposts' => -1,

        'order' => 'ASC',

        'post_mime_type' => 'image',

        'post_parent' => $posid,

        'post_status' => null,

        'post_type' => 'attachment',

    );



    $atts = get_children( $args );

  $tatts = count($atts);


  $i = 1;

  shuffle($atts);

  foreach ($atts as $at){    

    if ($i == 1){

      $atid = $at->ID;

      $mimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($atid,'medium');

      $msrc = $mimg[0];

      $mw = $mimg[1];

      $mh = $mimg[2];

 $atitle = ucwords(str_replace(array('-','_','+',),' ',$at->post_title));
 $atslug = $at->post_name;
 $aturl = $surl.'/'.$poslug.'/'.$atslug.'/';
 echo '<h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title"> More images </h3>';
 } else {      
 if($i>7) {} else {
 $atid = $at->ID;
 $mimg = wp_get_attachment_image_src($atid,'large');
$msrc = $mimg[0];
 $mw = $mimg[1];
  $mh = $mimg[2];
  echo '<p class="social_share clearfix"><img  src="'.$msrc.'"/></p>';  } }  $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: Please share your code of getting attachmets of single post.php

Comment: Hi, thanks and sorry for late reply, i update my question with code, please help me

Comment: @Kunal hi, any update?